# SELECT DISTINCT Users in Table 1 which don't exist in Table 2

Tags: sql, ms-access, except

I have a table with 4 columns of user information. Each table has the following columns:

```
Username | Full_Name | Job_Name | Current_Job_Allowed
```

Table 1 includes all users and the Job_Name which they have permissions to view. This means that there are multiple lines of the same username in Table 1 with different Job_Name values.

Table 2 contains a list of all possible users.

```
Username      |Full_Name
--------------+-----------------
amunoz        |Andrew Munoz
csmith        |Carl Smith
cwatkins      |Cat Watkins
ggriffiths    |Garmin Griffiths
jcarr         |Jason Carr
jhothi        |Jark Hothi
jphillips     |Jim Phillips
lbradfield    |Lisa Bradfield
ntaylor       |Noria Taylor
rfelipe       |Ralf Felipe
```

Query 1 contains all users specified by a query parameter which I specify, i.e. 'KML_20160531'.

I would like to now select a DISTINCT list of all users which have a different Job_Name from the parameter I specify for Job_Name. For example Table 1 contains:

```
Username|Full_Name   |Job_Name    |Current_Job_Allowed
--------+------------+------------+----------------------
amunoz  |Andrew Munoz|KML_20160531|1
jcarr   |Jason Carr  |KML_20160531|1
rfelipe |Ralf Felipe |KML_20140531|1
amunoz  |Andrew Munoz|KML_20160431|1
```

I would then like to return the below when I enter 20160531 for Job_Name. This will return all possible new users for the Job_Name value I entered.

```
Username      |Full_Name
--------------+---------------
csmith        |Carl Smith
cwatkins      |Cat Watkins
ggriffiths    |Garmin Griffiths
jhothi        |Jark Hothi
jphillips     |Jim Phillips
lbradfield    |Lisa Bradfield
ntaylor       |Noria Taylor
rfelipe       |Ralf Felipe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter query will show you which users have a `Table 1` row with `Job_Name` matching the parameter value:

```sql
PARAMETERS which_job Text ( 255 );
SELECT t1.[Username], t1.Job_Name
FROM [Table 1] AS t1
WHERE t1.Job_Name=[which_job];
```

So you can use that as a subquery, left join `Table 2` to the subquery, and select the rows where the "right side" is Null:

```sql
PARAMETERS which_job Text ( 255 );
SELECT t2.[Username]
FROM
    [Table 2] AS t2
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT t1.[Username]
            FROM [Table 1] AS t1
            WHERE t1.Job_Name=[which_job]
        ) AS sub
    ON t2.[Username] = sub.[Username]
WHERE sub.[Username] Is Null;
```

Assuming that query returns the correct rows, add the other field you want to see to `SELECT t2.[Username]`.

You should not need `DISTINCT` unless `Table 2` allows duplicate `Username` values, or `Table 1` allows more than one row with the same combination of `Username` and `Job_Name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use not in and distinct

```
select distinct a.username, a.fullname 
from table1 as a 
where a.username not in (select distinct username  
                  from table2 where job_name ='my_value');
```

and for only the job

```
select distinct a.username, a.fullname 
from table1 as a 
where a.username not in (select  username  
                   from table2 
                   group by username 
                   having count(job_name) = 1 
                   and job_name ='my_value'   );
```

Comment: Hi, this case won't return the correct result if the user has another job under their name. For example, amunoz would still be returned because they have Job_Name KML_20160431.

Comment: You want exclude only the names that are only the job_name ?? but if have other joib you want these name is select ?

Comment: I have update the answer for getting the username when  there is more then a job ..

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `DISTINCT` for this query at all:

```
select t.*
from table1 as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 as t2
                  where t2.username = t.username and t2.job_name = "KML_20160531"
                 );
```

From your description of the problem, `Current_Job_Allowed` does not seem relevant.

Comment: Hi, this case won't return the correct result if the user has another job under their name. For example, amunoz would still be returned because they have Job_Name KML_20160431.

Comment: @ConradAddo . . . No, that is not how `not exists` works.

Answer (score 0):

This will be syntax for your problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserName 
FROM Table1 
WHERE UserName NOT IN (
    SELECT UserName From Table2 
    WHERE job_name = ''
);
```

Comment: Hi, this case won't return the correct result if the user has another job under their name. For example, amunoz would still be returned because they have Job_Name KML_20160431.